# MySQL order by date doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am having php code like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../Php/ConfigBaza.php");

    $kid = $_SESSION['KORISNIKID'];

    $sql = "SELECT REZERVACIJAID, DATE_FORMAT(DATUM, '%d.%m.%y') AS DATUM, 
                    STATUS, VREDNOST 
            FROM REZERVACIJE 
            WHERE KORISNIKID = '$kid' 
            ORDER BY DATUM DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo("Nemate ni jednu rezervaciju!");
        die();
    } else {
        echo("<style>");
        include('../Styles/_Rezervacije.css');
        echo("</style>");
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $realizovana = "";
            $rid = $r['REZERVACIJAID'];
            $h_rid = hash('fnv1a32', $rid);
            $datum = $r['DATUM'];
            $status = $r['STATUS'];
            $v = $r['VREDNOST'];

            $v_txt = number_format($v, 2);

            if($status == 2) {
                $realizovana = "realizovana";
            } else if($status == 0) {
                $realizovana = "neaktivna";
            }
            echo("
                <div class='rezervacija $realizovana' id='$rid' onclick='IdiNaRezervaciju(this.id)'>
                    <p style='font-weight: bolder; font-size: large'>$h_rid</p>
                    <br>
                    <p style='font-size: large'>$v_txt</p>
                    <p style='font-weight: bolder'>$datum</p>
                </div>
            ");
        }
    }
?>
```

as you can see in query i am ordering by date but for some reason it does normaly for days but not for months.

Result i am getting is:

[image]

In mysql database my date column is type of date

[image]

Comment: You have made DATUM a date in format `'%d.%m.%y'` which wont sort well. Suggest you dont use the same alias for DATUM i.e. use `as DATUM_USER` and then it will sort of the original DATUM column in your table which is a proper formatted DATE type and Will sort well

Comment: @RiggsFolly - You're too quick. I was literally 4 seconds from posting an almost identical comment. :-o

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Great Minds think alike

Comment: Suppose one of us should post this as an answer. All yours if you want to @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Nah... it's yours. You've earned it. You could also use this fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d2e5f/1. It's on the house ;-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No, if you have bothered to do a fiddle, thats great, you go ahead and answer it

Comment: @RiggsFolly - You win. Answer posted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @RiggsFolly brilliantly mentioned in his comment, the problem is that you're reformatting the date column you're using to sort the records.

When you reformat the date column, MySQL won't read it as a date field anymore but rather as text, and as text, `04.08.18` is lower than `31.08.18` which is why you're getting the order you're currently getting.

The solution is simply to reformat the date column as another name:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATUM, '%d.%m.%y') AS SOME_DATE,
```

You can of course change `SOME_DATE` to what ever you want. Then in your code, you fetch it with  `$r['SOME_DATE'];` instead.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the difference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d2e5f/1

Comment: I saw that too ;-)

Comment: See your descritption is so much better than mine :)

Comment: You still have your own way with words @Riggs ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Haha. Hard to be as thorough in a comment, though ;-)

Comment: Meet @FunkFortyNiner the stackoverflow dynamic spell checker. :) :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Already fixed :-) What is it with English and adding a bunch of unnecessary letters in all the words? No KISS there..

Comment: Pleased tah meetch ya @RiggsFolly

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah I know; 'tis the way of the land. Ask Riggs; he lives in the olde Country.

Comment: Glad to have you back by the way @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm only on here when I'm not working 'round the house. Mother Nature usually has her way with me, but I tend to throw her back a bone to pick with.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner [pleased to meet cha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX6EvFtRll8)

Comment: Wow, this is the first SO bro-mance I see!  Thanks for the memories :-)

Comment: @Nic3500 :) How do you know we are all Bro's ?

Comment: Sorry for assumption, I just have never met a PHP dev. that is not a Bro ;-)